# Appcelerator SSL Certificate Invalid

Tags: ios, ssl, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

It seems that most of Appcelerator's subdomains are having SSL issues, causing an issue in Titanium's iOS build process.

Does anyone also have this issue?
If so, is there a workaround to get the build process working.

I tried cleaning the project, explicitly trusting their invalid certificate, and disconnecting from the internet during build (produced different results but still failed).

Ex. https://security.appcelerator.com

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=security.appcelerator.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not alone, I am also seeing it and so are others...I also do nto think there is a workaround at this point

Appcelerator's response:
https://twitter.com/appcelerator/status/735908332054151170